# How does Oracle SQL*Plus read script files?

Tags: oracle, scripting, sqlplus

Theory question: How does Oracle's SQL*Plus read script files into memory?

It likely does one of these two options:

1. Opens the file, reads the entire contents into memory, closes the file, and executes the contents from memory.
2. Opens the file, reads and executes statements sequentially, closes the file.

Does anyone know for sure which method it uses?

Im writing a program that will modify a script, run the script, and then modify again. This will be simplest if I can modify the script even if it is currently running (Option 1). If Option 2, I will have to wait for the script to be done before I modify again.

Comment: or......buffers

Comment: It executes statements sequentially. If you modify a file while it's being executed those modifications might take effect